# Changing the behaviour of a Software

Tags: windows, installation, uac

I have a msi file when I install it writes instructions to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE;and give UAC to user to do it or not I want to edit this behaviour I mean prompting for a UAC in a way that it will do all the installation without prompting to user for a UAC in windows 7.My question is what needs to be modify in a file.

Answer (score 0):

When UAC is enabled an elevation dialog is always required to get the privileges to write to HKLM. There isn't anything you can modify to prevent this requirement for elevated privilege. You could run the MSI as administrator, or start it from an exe (but the exe will require an elevation dialog anyway), but again these are just ways to get the required elevated privileges.

So you could open the MSI file with Orca, View Summary Information, and then check the UAC compliant box, but if the install really requires elevation then the install will fail with "You do not have sufficient privileges...."

Comment: If we want all instructions write on HKCU then what changes we require

Comment: I need installation without asking user for UAC for this what options are available?

Comment: See that 2nd paragraph about the UAC compliant box if you want to write to HKCU and don't require elevation for anything the install does,